# Mount new USB drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, backup, deja-dup

I have issue mounting an usb drive.

After inserting the usb drive, I format disc via Disks app and then create partition ext4.

After confirming the Disks app close.

Then I am trying to mount but without success.

The command that I run is below:

sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /media/usbdrive

Error appear:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

```
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Create partition screen:
https://ibb.co/iqTECo

Disks details:
https://ibb.co/cPJLk8

What I am doing wrong?

I want to use this as backup using deja dup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually appears when the drive is corrupted.
The kernel is unable to read the filesystem superblock, which contains important information regarding the structure of the filesystem.
I suggest you to try formatting the drive once more, using `GParted`.
Also try creating a smaller partition towards the end of the drive.
It may be that the blocks of the drive at the beginning is damaged.

**Update:**
Reformatting the drive did not fix the issue.
Using `GParted`, a new `msdos` partition table (also called MBR) was created.
Created a new partition and formatted it as Ext4 (quick format).
The drive was able to be mounted successfully.

Comment: Thanks for tip.. But when I open gparted, I don't even see on the list the usb...

This was clean usb, I have installed IOS of ubuntu for install. 

Then I try format and partition, and failed on mount.

Comment: Can you please guide me, even command line or via gui.. for format, partition and mount. thanks

Comment: Sure. Are you on IRC?

Comment: What is IOS of ubuntu?

Comment: ISO I think, makes sense in context

Comment: I am not on IRC, but I can join if required. I am using 16.04. 

@jrtapsell not sure what you mean

Comment: You can contact me at happycoder97 on freenode.

Comment: I have join happycoder97, my nick is zoroaster

Comment: Thanks for your support. Using gparted and following your instruction worked perfectly.

Comment: @Farzeen if you gave additional instructions on IRC, please make sure they are included in the answer.