# HDD extracting data problem

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have mounted the second HDD when I was using Linux OS and stored a lot of important data there. After changing the OS to Windows I tried to set the partition letter from Windows Disk Manager (without formatting) and get access to my files, but Windows was trying to format the HDD and now I could not mount this HDD in Linux. I would like to copy my files and then I can do formatting.

Mount error:

```
mount: /media/storage2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Disk information:

```
End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048      32767      30720    15M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  32768 1953521663 1953488896 931.5G Linux root (x86-64)

/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fca69f38-f4e1-4430-af90-75ad9ad23e64"
/dev/sda1: UUID="06db6b5b-a6c3-4547-a22d-88346fe2db33" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="17896779-dc5b-4e8c-908f-0f189ef3a0af"

Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM003-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D92680C1-7C6F-406D-BF2A-018C118A58D7
```

Comment: Windows does not read Linux partitions. There are a few third party tools but they are not recommended. You should be able to use the live installer you used to install Ubuntu or download a new live installer and use it in live mode. You may have issues with ownership/permissions as live installer is user 999 and your install was user 1000. You may be able to use sudo & manually mount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount new USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045014/mount-new-usb-drive)